# How can I run pip without a sudo (for mac)? It doesnt work without sudo

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, pip

I am trying to install python and pip. When I try to install pip, it says that it's already present,
running the below command,

```
python get-pip.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-   py2.7.egg
```

But when I try the pip command, it says

```
user1$ pip
-bash: pip: command not found
```

How do I solve this ?

Comment: Look in /Library/Python/2.7/scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it was a sudo issue, you wouldn't be getting "command not found". Try an alias instead:

`cd ~`

`vim .bashrc` (or equivalent text editor if you don't have vim)

`alias pip="path to pip"` (obviously you'll want to put in the actual path)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find where it is.

`locate pip`

You're looking for the binary so you want to narrow it down to ..../bin/.... paths, generally.

`locate pip | grep bin`

As an alternative to the above, if you can run `pip` while under sudo, try running `sudo which pip` to give you the path to it.

Once you find something promising (mine is `/usr/bin/pip`, for example), open up `~/.bashrc` and add a line `alias pip=your/bin/path`. Then you have to update bash's source so do `source ~/.bashrc` and you should be able to run `pip`.

As a sidenote, I (and many others) prefer to keep all of my `alias` definitions in a separate file to keep things clean, so I use `~/.bash-aliases` for all of my alias definitions and then in `~/.bashrc` you want these lines:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Which pulls all the aliases out of `~/.bash-aliases` for you.

Comment: The final tip is a good one. However, is it on purpose that you use a hyphen (dash) in the filename but an underscore in those lines insde `bashrc`? or is it an error?