# How can I run pip without sudo?

Tags: python, pip, sudo, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Command `pip` doesn't work without `sudo`

I was happily using `pip` with `sudo` but I have read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802544/is-sudo-pip-install-still-a-broken-practice) that I shouldn't do that.

However, when I try to use `pip` without `sudo` I get this:

```
[souto@~]$ pip install <package-name>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

I have tried James Sullivan's [tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23839389/how-can-i-run-pip-without-a-sudo-for-mac-it-doesnt-work-without-sudo) so my `.bash_history` file has the content below but to no avail.

```
[souto@~]$ cat .bash_aliases
alias pip=/usr/bin/pip
```

I am working on WSL, in case this is relevant.

Comment: The question you link to has an example which links to `virtualenv` which is really the answer here. Like many questions on Ask Ubuntu, the answers are not exactly precise or analytical there (nor is the question in this case).

Comment: Did you add your pip in your PATH ?

Comment: Thanks, triplee. However, I would like to use python and pip without a `virtualenv` (at least for the time being, I don't need that -- I'm working on my own machine and I'm the only user).

Comment: No, hissroth. I don't think I have done that (well, I'm not sure). How do I do that? Shall I just do `export PATH=/usr/bin/pip:$PATH` or is there anything else needed?

Comment: @tripleee, does your comment (and marking my question as duplicate) mean that creating a virtual environment (`virtualenv`) is the only way to run `pip` without `sudo`?

Comment: The duplicate contains alternatives, such as `pip install --user`.

Comment: You add directories to your `PATH`. If your `pip` is in `/usr/bin/pip` then `/usr/bin` is what needs to be on your `PATH` (but it should already be there, so no need to add it).

Comment: `virtualenv` also shields you from yourself. If you are only ever going to run a single Python script on your computer then by all means regard it as a throwaway OS and install everything you need with `sudo`. If that is not your scenario, you are probably going to want to use more than one set of libraries, and so `virtualenv` is useful hygiene.

Comment: Thanks, @tripleee. I thought `virtualenv` was a complication I can live without, but I'll give it a chance. This is only for python2 -- I don't need to use `sudo` with python3, so I don't need to use `virtualenv` either. Thanks.

Comment: I found the answer to my question here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1106328/230240. @tripleee, I don't think my question is a duplicate (I'm raising a different issue than the one you have linked to). I appreciate the tips to use `virtualenv` and I see the value of it, but probably that should be a choice and that's not the answer to my question (it didn't fix my issue).

Comment: Thanks for following up; I added a second duplicate.